# How to evaluate a function for a certain output list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find the output of a langrange interpolation function and predict the interpolated values from the equation post fitting the curve.
I have got the code for the function from a website. However I presume it just stores the equation in a format whereas I expect a result of values for the list supplied.

```
def langrange_polynomial(X, Y):
    def L(i):
        return lambda x: np.prod([(x-X[j])/(X[i]-X[j]) for j in range(len(X)) if i != j]) * Y[i]
    Sx = [L(i) for i in range(len(X))]  # summands
    return lambda x: np.sum([s(x) for s in Sx])
```

Expectation is for the given function evaluate or predict the function at a certain value or list i.e.if I pass a list of numbers [2,3,4,5], i should get the corresponding output value f(x) where f(x) is my lagrange equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the `langrange_polynomial` function returns a special kind of function in python, called a "lambda function". You can read about lambdas here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

To use your code just assign the output of the `langrange_polynomial` to a variable (which will be of type function) and then use that variable as a usual function luke such:

```
f = langrange_polynomial(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
f([3,60,30])
# output
3.115663712769497e+21
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. However, I just need to add a loop as evaluation of equation is for each individual value.

Comment: Glad it helped. I just tried to solve your technical python-related issue, did not look at your particular implementation of the Lagrange multipliers algorithm.